# MongoDB In-Memory Storage engine

Tags: mongodb

We are currently using the Wired Tiger storage engine with MongoDB 3.2
We have tweaked a server (196Go RAM, disable journal) in order to use mongodb as a cache server (no replication, write concern = 0 for fire & forget writes).

I'd like to know if it could be interesting for us to switch to the In Memory storage engine knowing that our data already fits in memory. Is there another benefits?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by how you have configured this sever as a cache server. When you say no replication, do you mean that it is not part of any replica set - and if so, where does it get its data from?

Comment: Yes, it is not part of a replicaset because we don't need high availabilityfor cache. When I say "Cache server" I mean a server with enough memory to fit all its data in RAM : no need to seek data on disk. So I wonder if it's worth to update to the the built-in in-memory built-in storage. What it could bring us.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already disabled journaling and the data fits your memory, switching to In-memory storage engine makes more sense as it provides the performance benefits that comes with the engine.
Just make sure that writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault to false, not sure if write concern=0 servers the same purpose during write ACKs.